# Why can I not use a TimePickerDialog to get the hours and minutes?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, timepicker

I'm trying to fix a small problem with my application allow me to paint you a picture.

Scenario:

In my application I have two edit texts which the user can select. They have both been setup as DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog boxes which when the first box is select will display a calendar in a dialog box and when the other is selected this will show a simple clock which allows the user to select a time. This will then set the text to the edit text.

Problem:

The problem I'm having is now I want my calendar to receive some information from these dialog boxes. When I come to get the information from the DatePickerDialog box I can use the code as below.

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, dialog.getDatePicker().getMonth());
```

Which is perfect but Android will not allow me to do the same with a TimePickerDialog. But I can do it from a standard Timepicker please example below.

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timepicker.getHour());
```

Is there something small that I'm missing? I have also included a copy on my onclick listener from the TimePickerDialog.

```
 timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(AlarmActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            hour_x = hourOfDay;
            minute_x = minute;

            String AM_PM ;
            if(hourOfDay < 12) {
                AM_PM = "AM";

            } else {
                AM_PM = "PM";
                hour_x=hour_x-12;
            }
            txtTime.setText(hour_x+":"+minute_x+" "+AM_PM);
        }
    }
    , hour_x,minute_x, true);
   timePickerDialog.show();
```

Thank you for reading and hopefully you can help with this small issue.

Comment: Did you get an error message or what kind of output you get and what output did you expect. Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: What is the problem to get the hour and minutes from the **TimePicker**? The TimePickerDialog doesn't have methods for providing hour and minutes.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Alex I'm not getting an error because I cannot put TimerPickerDialog.gethour for example. Hi Slavi what I was trying to do is get it from the TimePickerDialog the same way as I get a day or a month from the DatePickerDialog. The main reason I haven't used a TimePicker directly is because I don't want it on the screen all the time but instead only as a dialog box when the users clicks the edittext. How would you go around the problem? Thanks

Comment: I did not understand you fully. If you don't want to use the TimePicker at all, why do you set hour and minutes to a TextViewt? What is this EditText that the user is supposed to click on?

Comment: Ok that's fine. Firstly the user selects the edit text a TimePicker will then pop up in the form of a TimerPickerDialog. The user then selects the specified time its then sent back to the edit text. I hope this clarifies the issue.

Comment: You can use **calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timepicker.getHour());**, but instead of using **timepicker.getHour()** you can use the variables **hour_x** and **minute_x** for the calendar. For example: **calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour_x);**.

Comment: Thanks if you want to put that as an answer I will up vote it.